# Loop with javascript 101 102 …

Tags: javascript

I am trying to traverse 101 102 103 with JavaScript...

**I want to print as follows:**

```
101
102
103
104
105
106
…
150
151
…
```

My code:

```js
num = 180;
for (var i = 1; i < num; i++) {
  console.log('10' + i);
}
```

Comment: How about starting `i` from 101 and then logging `i`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this -

```
for(var i=101; i<180; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

'10' is a string. When you add a string with a num, the num will be transform to its string representation and concat the string.

```
num = 180;
for (var i=101; i<=num; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```